# Manga about princess who repeatedly kills herself after failed marriages to the crown prince and reincarnates

Tags: story-identification, manga

It starts on the day that she chooses her husband to marry and does not pick the crown prince. She is cold to her new fiancé even though she chose to be with him. Later it is revealed that she has been reincarnated several times after committing suicide due to her marriage with the crown prince. In her reincarnated lives she continues to have failed marriages to the crown prince, so now she chooses someone else to marry.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any of the characters or places?  If her new husband isn't the crown prince, who is he?  (Another noble, a soldier, a merchant...)

Answer (score 1):

This is *[The Broken Ring: This Marriage Will Fail Anyway](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-broken-ring-this-marriage-will-fail-anyway)*. It is licensed by [Tappytoon](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/book/the-broken-ring).

> When six-year-old Inés laid eyes on the handsome heir to House Escalante, **she promptly made the boy her fiancé**. Since noble men are all the same, she figured she might as well choose a pretty one. But Lord Cárcel isn't ready for this sort of commitment just yet, and he spends the next decade and a half avoiding the marriage at all costs! Luckily, that's no trouble for Inés, as **this marriage failing is exactly what she wants. In fact, he has her blessing to sow his wild oats as long as he stays out of her business**.

The synopsis covers the background, but not the details of the reincarnation or suicides. These do occur.

The story opens with the male lead, Cárcel Escalante flirting with other noble women despite being engaged to Ines. Ines is fully aware of his infidelity, and doesn't care at all.

[image]

The story flashes back to when they were 6 and first got engaged in a political marriage. Ines flatly refused the crown prince and explicitly chose Carcel. Carcel took this to mean that she liked him, despite her always cold appearance.

It is later revealed that she has reincarnated multiple times, and married the prince in her first life. The married life was horrendous, with him cheating on her and infecting her with diseases, then blaming her for miscarriages. This involves at least one suicide, although she may have just been murdered the first time. Her explicit choice of Carcel was just to have someone she's officially married to, who wouldn't bother actually staying with her.